# How to design Composite Pattern with Lazy Initialization and Null Object Pattern while SOLID Principles are followed?

Tags: python, solid-principles, lazy-initialization, liskov-substitution-principle, null-object-pattern

An Python example of tree shows the initial idea of Composite Pattern and Lazy Initialization.

```py
class Node:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
        self._lchild = None
        self._rchild = None

    def set_lchild(self, node):
        self._lchild = node

    def set_rchild(self, node):
        self._rchild = node


    def sum(self):
        sum = self._val
        if self._lchild is not None:
            sum += self._lchild.sum()
        if self._rchild is not None:
            sum += self._rchild.sum()
        return sum


root = Node(1)
lchild = Node(2)
root.set_lchild(lchild)
root.sum()
```

To avoid null check, Null Object Pattern is introduced.

```py
class Node(ABC):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
        self._lchild = NullNode(0)
        self._rchild = NullNode(0)

    def set_lchild(self, node):
        self._lchild = node

    def set_rchild(self, node):
        self._rchild = node

    @abstractmethod
    def is_null(self):
        return NotImplemented

    @abstractmethod
    def sum(self):
        return NotImplemented



class RegularNode(Node):

    def is_null(self):
        return False


    def sum(self):
        sum = self._val
        if not self._lchild.is_null():
            sum += self._lchild.sum()
        if not self._rchild.is_null():
            sum += self._rchild.sum()
        return sum 


class NullNode(Node):
    def is_null(self):
        return True

    def sum(self):
        return 0


root = RegularNode(1)
lchild = RegularNode(2)
root.set_lchild(lchild)
root.sum()
```

To obey Liskov Substitution Principle, the example is revised.

```py
class Node(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def is_null(self):
        return NotImplemented

    @abstractmethod
    def sum(self):
        return NotImplemented

class RegularNode(Node):

    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val
        self._lchild = NullNode()
        self._rchild = NullNode()

    def set_lchild(self, node):
        self._lchild = node

    def set_rchild(self, node):
        self._rchild = node

    def is_null(self):
        return False

    def sum(self):
        sum = self._val
        if not self._lchild.is_null():
            sum += self._lchild.sum()
        if not self._rchild.is_null():
            sum += self._rchild.sum()
        return sum 

class NullNode(Node):

    def is_null(self):
        return True

    def sum(self):
        return 0

root = RegularNode(1)
lchild = RegularNode(2)
root.set_lchild(lchild)
root.sum()
```

This makes `RegularNode` depend on its sibling `NullNode`.

And I'm not sure whether the dependency violates Dependency Inversion Principle.

If so, how to satisfy requirements above while no more SOLID Principle is violated?

In the examples above, any attemption will violate an SOLID principle.

The best scenario is no SOLID Principle is violated.
Otherwise, which principle would be OK to compromise in normal cases?

Comment: Please try [codereview.se] instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The whole point of the Null Object Pattern is to avoid checking whether something is null or not. Instead, the null object does nothing, or returns values appropriate for the "nothing" case.

In your case, you've already done this with the `sum` method by declaring the `NullNode` implementation to be

```py
    def sum(self):
        return 0
```

So the `sum` method of `RegularNode` no longer needs to check anything about whether the left or right child is null. Instead, the Null Object Pattern lets us simplify the `sum` to:

```py
    def sum(self):
        sum = self._val
        sum += self._lchild.sum()
        sum += self._rchild.sum()
        return sum
```

This works because adding 0 has no effect.

The `is_null` method goes away. All that is left in the base `Node` class is the abstract method `sum`. Nice and clean.

It's fine for `RegularNode` to depend on `NullNode` because the dependency is one way.